# Trying to run a subquery in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Trying to get a subquery going to find out which countries have more than 20 cities in this database (the dvdrental database from postgres). I am getting a syntax error message for "SELECT COUNT(c.city)" any idea to help fix it would be appreciated.

```
SELECT * 
FROM g
(SELECT COUNT(c.city) AS number_cities, co.country
FROM city c
JOIN country co
ON c.country_id= co.country_id
GROUP BY co.country
ORDER BY country)g
WHERE COUNT(c.city)>=20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `g` in `select * from g`

it should be

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(c.city) AS number_cities, co.country 
    FROM city c 
    JOIN country co ON c.country_id= co.country_id 
    GROUP BY co.country ORDER BY country) g 
WHERE number_cities>= 20
```

or you can remove the subquery, and use `having` instead

```
SELECT COUNT(c.city) AS number_cities, co.country 
FROM city c 
JOIN country co ON c.country_id= co.country_id 
GROUP BY co.country 
HAVING COUNT(c.city)>=20
ORDER BY country
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting this error message: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "c"
LINE 6: WHERE COUNT(c.city)>= 20

Comment: the `c` is no longer exists, u can rename it to make it simpler. Gonna update my answer